# BigQuery: "unexpected LIMIT clause at:" error when using list query job

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I ran a simple select query (with no LIMIT applied) using the Big Query python api. I also supplied a destination table as the result was too large. When run, the job returned an "unexpected LIMIT clause" error. I used ignore case at the end of the query. There could be a possibility that it might be causing the problem.

Anybody ran into a similar problem?

For reference, my job_id is job_QrkB7t9WFEHqcH5qfsPZZsM476E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is an artifact of how bigquery does "allow large results" queries interacting poorly with the "ignore case" clause. We're tracking an internal bug on the issue, and hopefully will have a fix soon. The workaround is either to remove the "allow large results" flag or the "ignore case" clause.

Comment: This is still an issue. Using PHP SDK from AppEngine. Was able to successfully process results when removing allow large results flag. I'm a bit concerned what will happen in the event that a large results set gets returned. Any updates on this?

Comment: Eric ... do you java a job ID of a job that hits this problem?